# Writing a function in php

Tags: php, function, echo

I am trying to work out how to write php functions, so that I don't have to keep writing a block of code over and over again, I am having a play around and tried writing this, but it doesnt work for some reason, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong ?.

```
<?php
$greeting 'Hello';

function frank ()
{
$name = 'frank';
$2nd = 'robson';
echo $greeting;
echo $name;
echo $2nd;
}


echo frank()
?>
```

Comment: Either [return the value you want to echo from the function](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php), or just call `frank()` (no `echo` beforehand). Also, you're missing an `=` from the first line and a `;` from the last.

Comment: Iain, see my answer. I explained.

Comment: also, can't have a variable name start with a number ($2nd is invalid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of echoing inside your function you should consider returning a string with it. Also prefer passing a parameter instead of using global scope :

```
$greeting = 'Hello';

function frank ($funcGreetings)
{
    $name   = 'frank';
    $second = 'robson';
    //Concat variable together an return them
    return $funcGreetings.' '.$name.' '.$second;
}


echo frank($greeting);
```

Finally a variable name start with a **letter or an underscore** so `$2nd` is not a valid name.
See this [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) for more info on naming variable

Answer (score 2):

> where I am going wrong ?.

Several places.

> but it doesnt work for some reason

That's not an error message - PHP will give you meaningful messages about stuff it doesn't understand *if you configure it properly*.

If you are getting an error message then you should have included it in your question.

```
<?php
$greeting 'Hello';
```

Here's the first error - which will cause a parse failure. There should be an assignment operator in there e.g.

```
$greeting = 'Hello';
```

The next error is here:

```
$2nd = 'robson';
```

[Variables names](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) must begin with an underscore or letter - not a number

```
echo frank()
```

2 errors here.

The statement is not terminated with a ; - it may still parse OK but is very messy.

Also the frank function doesn't return a value to echo.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to pass in the $greeting variable for it to be in the functions scope - see the [PHP manual for variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). It is best avoid using `global`s as they are harder to debug and test.

Secondly, you have missed out the assignment for the `$greeting` variable.

Thirdly, you have forgotten to return the value from the function so it can be `echo`d out. See the [PHP manual for functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Fourth, `$2nd` is not a valid variable name. Variables must start with a letter. See the [relevant manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

```
$greeting = 'Hello';

function frank ($greeting) {
    $return = '';
    $name = 'frank';
    $second = 'robson';
    $return .= $greeting;
    $return .= $name;
    $return .= $second;
    return $return;
}

echo frank($greeting);
```

Comment: Explain the downvote please. This is a perfectly good answer to the question.

Comment: Hi, is that passing the $greeting into the function ?, one thing im confused with too is how to pass something defined outside a function into a function, so if inside the function I have $a + $b , and outside the function $a = 2 and $b = 2 , how do I pass these to use inside the variable ?.

Comment: This is described on the following manual pages: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1):

I see, you  that you want to function which will return  something string.
You can pass variable as an argument.
Things after return statement will be what you get by calling `frank()`

```
$greeting = 'Hello';
function frank ( $greeting) {
    $name = 'frank';
    $second = 'robson';
    return  $greeting." ".$name." ".$second;
}

echo frank ( $greeting );
```

Or if you want to use global variable in the function you must declared this by a `global` statement

```
$greeting = 'Hello';
function frank ( $greeting) {
        global $greeting;
        $name = 'frank';
        $second = 'robson';
        return  $greeting." ".$name." ".$second; // 
    }
echo frank ( $greeting );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the string as you are using your function with echo

So, do something like this

```
//this is inside frank
$ret = $greeting.$name.$2nd;
return $ret;
```

Second, `$greeting` is a variable declared outside the function definition. So, you should not use it inside the function definition.

You function will now look like this

```
function frank ()
{
$greeting = 'hello';
$name = 'frank';
$2nd = 'robson';
$ret = $greeting.$name.$2nd;
return $ret;
}
```

Also, there is an error in the first line. `$greeting 'Hello'` is incorrect. It should be `$greeting = 'Hello'` (You are missing the `=` sign).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$greeting = 'Hello';

function frank ()
{
  global $greeting;
  $name = 'frank';
  $2nd = 'robson';
  echo $greeting;
  echo $name;
  echo $2nd;
}


frank();
?>
```

You need to SET the variable and you need SEMICOLONS.