# GCM denying the access

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on GCM to send messages to android devices. It worked perfectly with in localhost. But when I tried with the remote server, GCM not allowing the to access it. It shows as "Failed to connect to : Permission denied". I thought, it is the problem with using the same api key for both localhost and remote server. I also changed the api key. Can anyone explain me whats the problem with this. Thanks. The GCM code goes like this.

```
<?php

class GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your `GOOGLE_API_KEY`. It is invalid I guess.

Comment: also check whether curl is enabled where you are deploying it

Comment: @SunilMishra: I created a new key for it. But still giving that error.

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe: How to check it. Please tell.

Comment: Check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433946/how-to-check-if-curl-is-enabled-or-disabled

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe: Curl Support enabled.

Comment: Is it enabled or you enabled it now? is it working now ?

Answer (score 0):

Clear all the IP Address from Server Key  Page of Google Console, maybe this will solve your problem. If not please contact in comments.

[image: GCM Server Key Page]