# Create a course in moodle using php

Tags: php, curl, moodle

I have been a searching a lot on this

I want to create a course using Web service API of moodle.
Things I understood so far are

1. There is a function named core_course_create_courses
2. Need to create a access token
3. I have a code which uses curl class which I dont know how to configure on my server(godaddy domain) hosting

Please someone have done this post code or suggest me some tutorial to follow.

Comment: Seeking for tutorial is off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please suggest me steps that I need to follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable web services in Moodle - https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Using_web_services

Then read through these instructions for creating a client - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

There is a php example here - https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients/tree/master/PHP-REST

Comment: Thank you very much for code I will try.Do I need to change settings in php.ini for the curl to operate

Comment: Check if php curl is enabled using one of these methods : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433946/how-to-check-if-curl-is-enabled-or-disabled - if its not enabled then you will need to contact your host.

Comment: Thank you so much ...It Worked for me

Comment: Is there any web service that moodle provides to create test under course like it create courses using core_course_create_courses