# how to test if curl is available in PHP without errors

Tags: php, curl, hide, suppress, error-suppression

I am trying to detect if curl is installed using PHP in a script run from the command line. I tried  the following:

```
if(@function_exists('curl_version')){
...
}
```

and

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');

if(is_callable('curl_init')){
...
}
```

but in both cases I get this message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/curl.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I would prefer to hide the error message, but it appears that the @ and the error_reporting don't work. Is there a different way to suppress this message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if curl is enabled or disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433946/how-to-check-if-curl-is-enabled-or-disabled)

Comment: Sounds like your issue is more to do with your configs still trying to reference the extension when it's not there. Note the `PHP Startup`.

Comment: As a good developer you never should prefere hiding errors, warnings etc. Combat the cause instead

Comment: `if(function_exists('curl_init')){ /* go curling! */ }else{ /* we are experiencing technical difficulties, please try again later */ }` will let you know if CURL is available but what's more important is that you hide all error messages from the user in a production system and log them. Review your error log weekly and fix any issues that arise.

Comment: `php -r 'echo function_exists("curl_init");'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could check your installed extionsions

```
    $needed_extensions = array('curl',  '... other extionsions to check');
    $missing_extensions = array();
    foreach ($needed_extensions as $needed_extension) {
        if (!extension_loaded($needed_extension)) {
            $missing_extensions[] = $needed_extension;
        }
    }
    if (count($missing_extensions) > 0) {
        echo 'This software needs the following extensions, please install/enable them: ' . implode(', ', $missing_extensions) . PHP_EOL;
        exit(1);
    }
```

'

Comment: I tried this and it correctly returned that the extension wasn't loaded, but the warning still appeared.

Comment: is it possible, that you've actived the extension in the php.ini file but it doesn't exist on your hard disk?