# PHP facebook api auto scrape

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api

I'm total beginner in php and i need to find up how to [scrape](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) some metadata automatically.

I've found a solution, but i dont know how to use it in php.

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

Could someone post a php script how it can looks like ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That’s a basic HTTP request. So go research how to make those with PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot (Y) :)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code) too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Hit curl with POST method. Read more about [curl](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/techniques-for-mastering-curl--net-8470). Please check curl is enable or not [curl check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433946/how-to-check-if-curl-is-enabled-or-disabled) before use.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.