# Curl working on local but not working on live domain

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$url="http://182.191.78.79:92/api/ERP/Login?UserName=xxx&Password=xxx&LocationId=";

$secretKey = "sk_test_1234567";



  // append the header putting the secret key and hash

  $request_headers = array();
//  $request_headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $secretKey;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
 // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch))
    {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
    // Show me the result

    $transaction = json_decode($data, TRUE);

    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($transaction);

  }
```

Comment: format your code and give a detailed description, please.

Comment: My most favorite troubleshooting question: What happens when you try? Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: Not working how? Error messages? Wrong result? Does the computer crash? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Turn on error reporting and execute the script. Then you may able to see PHP errors if there are any exceptions. Sometimes this may be a problem caused by your firewall.

Comment: Error: Failed to connect to 182.191.78.79 port 92: Connection refused

Comment: I found this error

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if curl is available in PHP on your server?

```
function _isCurl(){
    return function_exists('curl_version');
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433965/4934937

If your server is running php5 and using linux, you can try to install the package php5-curl, since it's not installed by default.

Comment: This function is returning 1

Comment: What does it mean same code is working on local Apache Server but not working on live domain.

Comment: according to your comment "Connection refused" - this seems to be a whitelist related error, so you may whitelist your live server's IP address.