# how to make curl work in uwamp newer php version

Tags: curl, moodle, uwamp

Curl works perfectly with the two default php versions in uwamp (3.1.0) for windows 10.
But when you install a newer version from the uwamp depot (for example php-7.2.7) something is wrong:

- Uwamp report curl as installed
- but it isn't working (try with code below)

  echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_version') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';

(from [how to check if curl is enabled or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433946/how-to-check-if-curl-is-enabled-or-disabled))

Has someone found a solution to make it work: either by taking away a dll that blocks it, or by adding the right path or the right dll somewhere?

It is really blocking the install of moodle.

Thanks for your help.